# redis make - linker input file not found: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, makefile, redis, clang

I'm trying to compile the `redis` [3.2 sourcecode](https://github.com/redis/redis/tree/3.2) on my ubuntu 22.04 machine.

I have latest `gcc`, `g++` and `clang` binaries on my path.

```
> gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

> g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

> clang --version
clang version 16.0.0
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

When I try to compile with `> make MALLOC=libc` I get the following error when building the `lua` dependency:

```
cc -Wall -DLUA_ANSI -DENABLE_CJSON_GLOBAL -DREDIS_STATIC='' -DLUA_USE_MKSTEMP  -O2   x86_64 -c -o lapi.o lapi.c
cc: warning: x86_64: linker input file unused because linking not done
cc: error: x86_64: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
```

From what I understand, the `-c` is forcing only compilation and **NOT** allowing linking, causing the failure.

But I can't figure out how the `-c` flag is creeping in and its source.

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is this `x86_64` in your compilation command?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : I'm not sure myself. All I did was to run the `make` command.

Comment: This dangling `x86_64` in the compilation command is wrong. I suggest to report to the developers (open an issue on Github, maybe). The only possibility to help you is to analyze in deep detail this package and its build system. I am not sure somebody here will want to do that.

Comment: Ok thank you. I was wondering if the issue is the setup on my machine that is causing this, some incorrect version of compiler tool chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

My environment had a `TARGET_ARCH` variable set to `x86_64` (`export TARGET_ARCH=x86_64`).

This was causing the dangling `x86_64` to end up in the compilation command, I'm not sure how.

When I unset it, the `make` command ran successfully.